# How do I get "dragAndDrop" to work with Selenium using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating a Selenium test for a web page that I am working on and I am getting stuck trying to use the `dragAndDrop` action. I need to use this action to re-order a wait list that I have. I am new when it comes to Selenium and i'm not sure if I am using correct syntax for the `dragAndDrop` action. I would appreciate it if someone could help lead me in the right direction. Below is my current code minus some other test I wrote.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const keys = webdriver.Key;
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const rp = require('request-promise');
const chai = require('chai');
const assert = chai.assert;
const expect = chai.expect;
const should = chai.should();
const WebElement = require('selenium-webdriver');
const actions = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/input');

driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

describe('This is for testing the Rewards Portal using Selenium', function() {
this.timeout(60000);

  it('Should reorder the customers', async function () {
        let drag = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="LiveScheduleList"]/ul/li[1]/div[2]'));
        let drop = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="LiveScheduleList"]/ul/li[2]/div[2]'));

        await driver.sleep(2500);

        await driver.executeScript("document.querySelector('#ChangeOrderBtn').click();");

        await driver.sleep(2500);

        await actions.dragAndDrop(drag, drop);

    });
};
```

When I run it I get this back:
`TypeError: actions.dragAndDrop is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You are using actions incorrectly.

Your code should look like...

```
await driver.
      actions().
      dragAndDrop(drag, drop);
```

PD: BTW, using sleep to synchronize your code is not a best practice...